# Finding and Replacing radio button text based on specific text

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to find and replace radio button text however, the code i have written removes the whole radio button and replaces it with text. 
I have 3 radio buttons in a table (low, med, high), I want to find the radio button with "high" and replace its text with something else like "finished".

This is my code to explain better:

```js
var tableRow = $("td").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == "High";
}).text("High", "Finished");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nf-filler-control-inner">
  <table id="ctl00_ctl40_g_c8f035da_e217_44d5_83e0_bff9b94d32fc_ctl00_ctl00_formFiller_FormView_ctl122_065ff240_02d6_4583_a9b1_948238768260" class="aspNetDisabled  nf-associated-control" data-use-attribute-as-value="data-nfChoiceValue" style="width:100%;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="aspNetDisabled" data-nfchoicevalue="Low"><input id="ctl00_ctl40_g_c8f035da_e217_44d5_83e0_bff9b94d32fc_ctl00_ctl00_formFiller_FormView_ctl122_065ff240_02d6_4583_a9b1_948238768260_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl40$g_c8f035da_e217_44d5_83e0_bff9b94d32fc$ctl00$ctl00$formFiller$FormView$ctl122$065ff240_02d6_4583_a9b1_948238768260" value="Low" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" formcontrolid="1a427d12-7f9d-4c49-97b1-e751e43c36ac"><label for="ctl00_ctl40_g_c8f035da_e217_44d5_83e0_bff9b94d32fc_ctl00_ctl00_formFiller_FormView_ctl122_065ff240_02d6_4583_a9b1_948238768260_0">Low</label></span></td>
        <td><span class="aspNetDisabled" data-nfchoicevalue="Medium"><input id="ctl00_ctl40_g_c8f035da_e217_44d5_83e0_bff9b94d32fc_ctl00_ctl00_formFiller_FormView_ctl122_065ff240_02d6_4583_a9b1_948238768260_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl40$g_c8f035da_e217_44d5_83e0_bff9b94d32fc$ctl00$ctl00$formFiller$FormView$ctl122$065ff240_02d6_4583_a9b1_948238768260" value="Medium" disabled="disabled"><label for="ctl00_ctl40_g_c8f035da_e217_44d5_83e0_bff9b94d32fc_ctl00_ctl00_formFiller_FormView_ctl122_065ff240_02d6_4583_a9b1_948238768260_1">Medium</label></span></td>
        <td><span class="aspNetDisabled" data-nfchoicevalue="High"><input id="ctl00_ctl40_g_c8f035da_e217_44d5_83e0_bff9b94d32fc_ctl00_ctl00_formFiller_FormView_ctl122_065ff240_02d6_4583_a9b1_948238768260_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl40$g_c8f035da_e217_44d5_83e0_bff9b94d32fc$ctl00$ctl00$formFiller$FormView$ctl122$065ff240_02d6_4583_a9b1_948238768260" value="High" disabled="disabled"><label for="ctl00_ctl40_g_c8f035da_e217_44d5_83e0_bff9b94d32fc_ctl00_ctl00_formFiller_FormView_ctl122_065ff240_02d6_4583_a9b1_948238768260_2">High</label></span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

code:

```
 var tableRow = $("td").filter(function() {
 return $(this).text() == "Medium";
}).text("High", "Finished");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To change label by label content you can use**

```
$("td label").filter(function() {
   return $.trim($(this).text()) == "Medium";
 }).text("Finished");
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ff0ysLrb/3/)

**To check the input value and change its label text you can use**

```
$("td input").filter(function() {
   return $.trim($(this).val()) == "Medium";
 }).closest('td').find('label').text("Finished");
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ff0ysLrb/4/)

> **Note:** I prefer to use $.trim(value/text) to avoid left and right white spaces